Is this an alternative realization of Deutsch's algorithm?
The standard Deutsch's algorithm uses two qubits and a control-$U_f$ gate, which transforms the two qubits,
$|x\rangle |-\rangle \rightarrow (-1)^{f(x)}\, |x\rangle  |-\rangle $. To realize the Deutsch's algorithm, the input state is $|+\rangle |-\rangle $, and the outcome state is $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2}}[ (-1)^{f(0)} \,|0\rangle  + (-1)^{f(1)}\, |1\rangle ]\ |-\rangle $ before a Hadamard gate and a measurement.
I am thinking of this alternative realization of Deutsch's algorithm: use one qubit and a $T_f$ gate, which transforms the qubit
$|x\rangle \rightarrow (-1)^{f(x)}\, |x\rangle $
and therefore
$|+\rangle \rightarrow \frac 1 {\sqrt {2}}[ (-1)^{f(0)}\, |0\rangle  + (-1)^{f(1)}\, |1\rangle ] = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (-1)^{f(0)}\, [\,|0\rangle + (-1)^{f(1)-f(0)}\, |1\rangle ]$. If this $T_f$ gate is followed by a Hadamard gate and a measurement, the outcome of 0 or 1 tells us whether $f(x)$ is constant or balanced.
The realization of the $T_f$ gate is simple if we consider the qubit is constructed by dual-rail waveguides. The 0 waveguide is subjected to a $f(0) \pi$ phase shift, and the 1 waveguide is subjected to a $f(1) \pi$ phase shift. The $T_f$ matrix is unitary $\begin{pmatrix} (-1)^{f(0)} & 0 \cr 0 & (-1)^{f(1)} \end{pmatrix}$
Is there anything wrong with this alternative realization?

Please use \rangle and \rightarrow instead of > and -> if you write expresions like this, because then it will look like $\rangle$ and $\rightarrow$. I took the liberty to change it in your text, for comparison see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/815418/revisions

No, there is nothing wrong. Does this answer your question?

Thanks for the changes.
